# Navigation drawer listview fragment

Tags: android

I want to make a navigation drawer which will populate by listview. Now i want that by clicking each item of the list, open a fragment as per my choice. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NavigationDrawer doesn't use a ListView in the menu, NavigationDrawer uses directly Menu Items it means that in your source code you can add programmatically items to your menu as you need.

Your NavigationDrawer activity or whatever you named

you can add items to the menu using the

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // To Inflate the menu:
    // this adds items to the navigation drawer menu if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    return true;
}
```

by default this method create a static menu using a XML layout in the res/menu/menu_file.xml

but if you follow the next source code you will be able to add more items to your navigation drawer programmatically

the Method add() overloads:

- add (int titleRes)
- add (CharSequence title)
- add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes);
- add (int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);

if you already have all the names of your new menu items in an array like itemsName
you can use something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    for(String itemName : itemsName){
       int itemId = Arrays.asList(itemsName).indexOf(itemName);
       menu.add(Menu.NONE, itemId, Menu.NONE, itemName);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and to manage the click event, on every one, you need to solve it depending on your array of actions to take, in your dynamic array, because you need to know deterministic every action that your menu item need to do or behave, as a menu option. 
But in general your click listener for those menu items you use something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    //here you need the logic of what action
    //your item is going to take
    //but that is up to you 
    //how do you want to know what to do
    //with a dynamic unknown array of options.
    if (itemId == 0){
       doSomething();
       return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

enjoy!!!

Comment: The options menu is wholly unrelated to the menu resource that `NavigationView` uses.